# How do I view the Eclipse Overview Workbench basics?

Tags: eclipse

I've just installed Eclipse 3.8 on Kubuntu 16.04.  I know nothing of Eclipse, so I thought I'd take advantage of its built-in Overview.

When I select "Workbench basics" from the Overview, the only thing that happens is a blank Emacs frame pops up.  What's happening, and how do I view the "Workbench basics" tutorial?

Comment: That's an old version, and if packaged by Kubuntu might not have been done right. You can probably make do with http://help.eclipse.org . As for why Emacs...I guess someone might have a proper Answer for that one.

Comment: It is probably trying to open a browser to display a HTML file. The current version of Eclipse is 4.6.1